# How to send correct JSON to Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, json.net

I'm new to the REST/JSON interface.

I'm working in VS 2013 C#, Framework is 4.5.

Right now I've successfully created items on a list in Sharepoint, using a JSON payload similar to this:

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ABCs_x0020_for_x0020_TAC_x0020_SiebelListItem' },
'Priority':'A',
'Requirements_x0020_Status':'Fully Documented',
'Status':'Under Consideration',
'Description':'This is a test',
'ABC_x0020_Type':'Enhancement',
'Title':'Testing: 921253434',
'Business_x0020_Unit_x0020_Affect':'TAC',
'AssignedToId':'1',
'Submitted_x0020_by':'sdsd',
'Applies_x0020_To':'Screens/Views',
'Screen_x002f_View_x002f_Module':'CSR'}
```

I was manually creating the JSON payload and decided to try out some objects that might help with the Serialization/Deserialization.

Here is the code:

```
            ABCItem item = new ABCItem();
         item.Title = "Testing " + ran.Next();
        item.ABC_x0020_Type = "Enchancement";
        item.Applies_x0020_To = "Screens/View";
        item.Priority = "A";
        item.Requirements_x0020_Status = "Fully Documented";
        item.Screen_x002f_View_x002f_Module = "CSR";
        item.Business_x0020_Unit_x0020_Affect = "TAC";
        item.Submitted_x0020_by = "Brian Hintze";
        item.Status = "Under Consideration";
        item.AssignedToId = 1;
        item.Description = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog and then drank a pint of beer.";


        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to get the __metadata part of the JSON payload to get added correctly. I've tried this

```
 item.__metadata = "{ 'type': 'SP.Data.ABCs_x0020_for_x0020_TAC_x0020_SiebelListItem' }";
```

But that didn't work.

I've tried fiddling around the MetaDataSettings, but so far I can't figure out the right combination.

```
           string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item,new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            // $type no longer needs to be first
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Default
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure it is something fairly basic that I'm missing.

thanks,

lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON serializer will convert objects to JavaScript objects.

Instead of making `item.__metadata` a string value, try making it an object with a member property called `Type` that equals "SP.Data.ABCs_x0020_for_x0020_TAC_x0020_SiebelListItem".

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to make the property __metadata be a reference to its own class. After all, this is a complex json object.

Using json2csharp.com [1](http://json2csharp.com/) you can see that your ABCItem class should look like

```
public class Metadata
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class ABCItem
{
    public Metadata __metadata { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

Comment: Thriggle beat you by 4 minutes, so he'll get the check-mark :)

But this is the detailed writeup of his answer.

Thanks!!